# Cartesian product of two dict in two lists in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Here is my code.

```
>>> a = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
>>> b = [{'c': 3}, {'d': 4}]
```

I want to show:

```
[{'a':1, 'c':3}, {'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':1, 'd':4}, {'b':2, 'd':4}]
```

Is there a way I can do it only with list/dict comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one line, no import solution can consist of a `lambda` function:

```
f = lambda d, c:[c] if not d else [i for k in d[0] for i in f(d[1:], {**c, **k})]

a = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
b = [{'c': 3}, {'d': 4}]
print(f([a, b], {}))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'd': 4}, {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'b': 2, 'd': 4}]
```

However, a much cleaner solution can include `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
result = [{**j, **k} for j, k in product(a, b)]
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'd': 4}, {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'b': 2, 'd': 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
a = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
b = [{'c': 3}, {'d': 4}]
d = [ {**i, **j} for i in a for j in b ]
print(d)
```